# How can I save the current Unix working directory in a variable?

Tags: directories

I know I can run `M-x pwd` which will give me `Directory ~/` or something like that. Can I get it without the "Directory" bit?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also add

```
(setq my-initial-directory default-directory)
```

to your Emacs init file.

In that way, you could later access the directory where Emacs was launched by evaluating `my-initial-directory`..

Answer (score 2):

Check the `default-directory` variable.

Comment: Thank you very much. However, `default-directory` changes with each found file. I'd like to find the "working directory" where Emacs have been launched.

Comment: Emacs doesn't rely on that notion. For a lot of people, it was launched 2 months ago. Don't close Emacs unless you're rebooting.

Comment: +1 `M-x pwd` just prints the message with the value of the variable `default-directory`

Answer (score 0):

I just found out I can do `(getenv "PWD")` on Linux on bash. I'm not sure if there's a better (more platform-agnostic and Emacs) way to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You can evaluate `(call-process "pwd" nil t)`, e.g. typing `M-:` `(call-process "pwd" nil t)` `RET`. This will run Unix `pwd` command and insert its output at the point in the current buffer, if the buffer is not read-only.  It's not clear from the question what for and why you need the current directory without `Directory` prefix.

Comment: Thank you, but I'd like to save it in a variable.